# I am writing a JSP page and why my request.getAttribute return null?

Tags: forms, jsp, servlets

I use this js function to submit my form.

```
function updateAction(obj,tableName){
  inputs=obj.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("input");
  newValues="";
  for(i=0;i<inputs.length;i++){
    newValues+=inputs[i].value+",";
  }
  obj.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.action="SimpleServlet?action=update&tableName="+tableName+"&newValue="+newValues;
  obj.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.submit();
}
```

and the action of form has correctly been changed to

```
"http://localhost:8081/SimpleWeb/SimpleServlet?action=delete&tableName=stude…01199203110000,200301,%E5%85%83%E5%AE%9D,%E7%94%B7,3,yb,424551199104010000,"
```

and in my servlet

```
String action=(String)request.getAttribute("action");
String tableName=(String)request.getAttribute("tableName");
System.out.print(request.getAttribute("tableName"));
System.out.print(request.getAttribute("action"));
System.out.print(request.getAttribute("newValue"));
String[] newValues=((String)request.getAttribute("newValue")).split(",");
```

but they are still null,why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sending your parameters by URL try using `request.getParameter(name);`

Comment: @Stillily are you still getting null values?

Comment: Ok, got the right values now, thx :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are sending parameters, try `request.getParameter`:

```
String action = request.getParameter("action");
```

`request.getAttribute` is used to get the attribute set on the server side using `request.setAttribute`.

Comment: Got the right values now, thx :-)